# Problems while trying to retrieve value from arraylist stored in session

Tags: asp.net

Please help me. Here is my code

```
ArrayList arrValues = new ArrayList();
arrValues = (ArrayList)Session["ArrValues"];

string CustName, Addr1, Addr2, City, State, Country, Pin, Email,Order,CustToken;
string SName, SAddr1, SAddr2, SCity, SState,SPin, SCountry;         

CustName = arrValues[1].ToString().Trim();
```

It is thrwoing a "NullReference excption" while trying to get the value of `CustName` from the arraylist stored in the session. Below is the link to see the video

http://www.talash.com/testingvideo/2011-03-18_0958_Payment_Gateway_Problem.swf

Comment: You shouldn't intitialize a new ArrayList with `ArrayList arrValues = new ArrayList();`. You don't avoid a NullReferenceException when your session-value is null but you are causing confusion with this code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your session variable doesn't exist.
arrValues is null. You need to look into why you are loosing your session variable.

Are you trying to get this value from within a page or a module?
If you work with HttpModule the session is not available at all times and it might be that the session object is null.

Answer (score 0):

since your session variable is not set to any value previously thats why u are getting an error.make this code safe by putting it inse something like this..

```
if(Session[Arrvalues"]!=null)
{

    //your block of code//

 }
else
 {
    Response.Redirect("to_the_page_where_this_session_variable_is_set.aspx");


  }
```